# Erro ao fazer insert no banco com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Estou tentando fazer o insert de dados no MySQL, não aparece nenhum erro porém não insere os valores no banco.

```
    <?php

        INCLUDE "conexao.php";


        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        $cod_produto = $_POST['cod_produto'];
        $dsc_produto = $_POST['dsc_produto'];
        $preco_produto = $_POST['preco_produto'];
        $qtd_estoque = $_POST['qtd_estoque'];



        $sql = "INSERT INTO estoque (cod_produto, dsc_produto, preco_produto, qtd_estoque) VALUES ('".$cod_produto."', '".$dsc_produto."', '".$preco_produto."', '".$qtd_estoque."')";
            if (!mysqli_query($sql)) {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error()); 
        }

        else
            echo" error";
        }

        ?>
```

Já testei a conexão e está ok.

---

Com a ajuda do pessoal eu consegui achar os erros.

1. o submit não estava funcionando, código correto:

   ```
   <button id="btn_aceitar" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" type="Submit">Adicionar produto</button>
   ```
2. estava esquecendo de chamar a query propriamente dita, código correto:

   ```
       <?php

       INCLUDE "conexao.php";


       if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

       $cod_produto = $_POST['cod_produto'];
       $dsc_produto = $_POST['dsc_produto'];
       $preco_produto = $_POST['preco_produto'];
       $qtd_estoque = $_POST['qtd_estoque'];



       $sql = "INSERT INTO estoque (cod_produto, dsc_produto, preco_produto, qtd_estoque) VALUES ('".$cod_produto."', '".$dsc_produto."', '".$preco_produto."', '".$qtd_estoque."')";
       $mysql = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
           if (!mysql) {
           die('Error: ' . mysqli_error()); 
       }

       else {
           echo "Completo";
       }
       }
       else {
           echo "submit error";
       }

       ?>
   ```

Valeu pessoal.

Comment: No seu código, se for verdadeiro apresenta erro e se for falso também. Os dados são inseridos?

Comment: Se resolveu o problema, pode criar uma resposta explicando os detalhes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código verifica se $_POST["submit"] é true.

É a unica parte do seu código que, se for false, não exibe erro algum. 
Verifique se está sendo passado algum valor para $_POST['submit'].

Comment: Boa! Acho que estou com algum erro no submit mesmo. Pra evitar injection, devo usar uma procedure de insert no lugar?

Comment: Para verificar se houve uma requisição tipo post, pode usar simplesmente um if($_POST). Para evitar injections você pode usar esta função (https://github.com/jrossetto/php/blob/master/functions/antiInjection.php) aplicada por um array_map no array $_POST.

Comment: Vou dar uma pesquisada, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Na função

```
mysqli_query($sql)
```

esta faltando o link da conexão com o banco de dados. Seria assim:

```
mysqli_query($link, $sql)
```

Acesse http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Boa! Na verdade eu esqueci de chamar a função em si, editei minha pergunta com o código corrigido.